# Mechanism timed by wheel rotations

Tags: mechanisms, mechanical, distance-measurement

I hope this is not off-topic. I’m wondering if someone could please provide some examples of a basic mechanism (I’m thinking something like a bevel/spiral gear, but open to anything) that is attached somewhere to a vehicle, and uses the rotation of the wheels as a timer/measure to perform a task. As a fake example, maybe it would be something attached to an axle and every 10m rings a bell. I’m talking totally mechanical, not involving electricity or computers. Thank you

Comment: Not on a vehicle, but a lathe with screw drive...

Comment: The closest thing I can think of is an [odometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odometer) which gives a reading of the distance a vehicle has traveled.

Comment: Look at the scotch yoke mechanisme, half a revolution of the driving wheel is equal to a linear motion of the shaft, so the time needed for horizontal translation. So if the wheel rotates at 2 rpm, then it can ring a bell once per every minute.

Comment: Umm,,,   a grandfather clock?